# What are the cases when the smart cast doesn't work?

Tags: kotlin

Now i am reading the book which is called "Kotlin in action" and there is the following text:

> The smart cast works only if a variable couldn’t have changed after the is check.
> When you’re using a smart cast with a property of a class, as in this example, the property has to be a val and it can’t have a custom accessor. Otherwise, it would not be possible to verify that every access to the property would return the same value.

Here's the example from it:

```
interface Expr
class Num(val value: Int) : Expr
class Sum(val left: Expr, val right: Expr) : Expr

fun eval(e: Expr): Int {
    if (e is Num) {
        val n = e as Num
        return n.value
    }
    if (e is Sum) {
        return eval(e.right) + eval(e.left)
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown expression")
}

fun main(){
    println(eval(Sum(Sum(Num(1), Num(2)), Num(4))))
}
```

I tried a bunch of options: changed an object instance and one of its property after is check, used var properties instead of val and also used custom accessors. In all cases is check works great.

```
interface face1
class A(): face1{
    var a = 1
        get() = field
        set(value){field = field+value}
}
class B(): face1{
    var b = 1
        get() = field
        set(value){field = field + value}
}

fun Test(x: face1){
    var value = x
    if(value is A){
        value = A()
        println("hello")
        value.a = 123
        println(value.a)
    }
    if(value is B)
        println(value.b)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val x: face1 = A()
    Test(x)
}
```

**So what does this text mean ?**

UPD:

Even in the official kotlin docs it is written that:

> Note that smart casts work only when the compiler can guarantee that the variable won't change between the check and its usage.

> var properties: Never, because the variable can be modified at any time by other code.

but my second example shows that is a lie.

Answer (score 1):

As the book specified, smart cast is possible if the compiler can guarantee the value didn't change between the check and use. In your case you used a local variable, there is no way anyone can modify this value in the meantime, so the smart cast is possible.

It becomes more complicated if we use properties, because then it all depends on the type of the property, how it was implemented, if it belongs to the same module or not, etc. However, the general rule is the same: if the compiler can guarantee no modifications, it will allow smart casts.

**Update**

You seem to confuse properties and local variables. You quote documentation for properties, but there are no properties in your code - only local variables. The [article you referenced](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) is clear about the behavior for local variables:

> `var` local variables - If the variable is not modified between the check and its usage, is not captured in a lambda that modifies it, and is not a local delegated property.

Which is exactly the behavior you observe.

Comment: I didn't read the book, so I can't say why they chose an example using a local variable. Isn't this the first example, showing what the smart cast even is and not going into more details yet?

Comment: excuse me, is parameter `e` in their example considered as a local variable ? I though local variables and parameters are different things. In that case can you show an example with is check and without local variables.

Comment: Yes, parameters passed to functions are represented inside them as local variables. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: `If the variable is not modified between the check and its usage`, but in my case it is

Comment: Sorry, which part of your code do you mean? `value = A()`? It also works as a smart cast - the compiler understands that after this line the type of `value` is `A`. If you would do `value = B()` instead, you could access `value.b`, but not `value.a`.

Comment: Indeed, if i assign something of `face1` type to `value`, my program doesn't get compiled. Thanks !

Comment: But what about properites ? The [article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) i referenced not only about local variables but also about properties. It states that i can't use `open` keyword or custom getters with `val` properties and `var` properties at all with smart casts. But my example gets compiled despite having custom accessors and if i add the `open` keyword to `a` and `b` properties, it will still get compiled. So what do i have to do with properties to see compilation error ?

Comment: We don't smart cast `a` or `b` here, but `value`. If we don't check the type of a local variable, but of a property, e.g.: `someObj.value` and this prop wouldn't meet additional requirements, smart cast would not work and we couldn't do e.g.: `someObj.value.a`.